# Visual Studio Designer - Limit property grid to show some specific languages for Language property

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, localization, windows-forms-designer

I am developing in Visual Studio 2013 (C#) and am searching for a way to make the selection of languages for a windows form easier for localization.

In the designer you have the possibility to select the language you want under "*Design*"→"*Language*" and Visual Studio does the rest by creating the necessary localization files if you need a new localized form.

The problem is: Currently I only work with two different languages, and every time when I switch between those localized forms it shows me a list of all possible languages, where a wrong click can cause visual studio to create localized version of a language I don't want, which is just annoying and clutters the project with more files.

Does anyone know a way to limit the languages shown in the designer options to a desired amount and selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language property is a design-time only property which doesn't belong to `Form` class. It's an extended property added using an extender provider to design-time of form. It is of type of `CultureInfo` and uses a `TypeConverter` which shows all available cultures.

As a workaround , you can have a `BaseForm` containing a property like `FormLanguage` and in the `get`, return value of `Language` property and in the `set`, set the value of `Language` property. Then inherit all your forms from this `BaseForm`. This way, it's enough to change `FormLanguage` property.

Also create a custom type converter for `CultureInfo` which shows only those culture which you want, then to change language, it's enough to change `FormLanguage` property.

[image: Localization Language]

Here is the code I used as workaround. Don't forget to inherit your forms from this `BaseClass`.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyCultureInfoConverter))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public CultureInfo FormLanguage
    {
        get
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["Language"]
                .GetValue(this) as CultureInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["Language"].SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
public class MyCultureInfoConverter : CultureInfoConverter
{
    public override StandardValuesCollection 
        GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var values = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures | 
            CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "fa-IR" || x.Name == "en-US").ToList();
        values.Insert(0, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }
}
```

When you select `fa-IR` from `FormLanguage` then the `Language` becomes `Persian` automatically because of the code which we wrote in setter of `FormLanguage`. You can add any other language which you need in `MyCultureInfoConverter`.

Comment: When you select `fa-IR` from `FormLanguage` then the `Language` becomes `Persian` automatically because of the code which we wrote in setter of `FormLanguage`. You can add any other language which you need in `MyCultureInfoConverter`. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a nice workaround to limit the selection. And it seems to work pretty fine. Switching from one language to the other works well and also the correct resx files are created. The problem I have right now (but this might be another issue) is that when I save the changes on in designer view, visual studio won't react anymore and I would have to kill it. But this might be a settings problem. I'll observe it the next days.

Comment: You are welcome, I didn't face with such problem. I'll checked it again. But you also check the behavior in a new and clean project and let me know the result.