# Switching between language forms in winforms

Tags: winforms, localization

I have a winforms C# application with German and default languages, only 2. I currently select the language dropdown and then find (default) to edit the default. To select the german form I select the language dropdown, and hit G G G G G G G to get to german or scroll down that long list to german and hit enter. Occasionally i go too far and select German-Austria, frustrating.

Is there a quick way to switch between localizable language forms in winforms rather then going to the properties window and selecting it in the language dropdown after they are formed? A shortcut key or anything?

Comment: [Visual Studio Designer - Limit property grid to show some specific languages for Language property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932205/3110834)

Comment: Certainly not very easy, seems the OP in that answer ran into serious problems with it.

Comment: For me, it worked properly. You can give it a try yourself and see the result. It's not a magical thing. You also have the option of changing the converter which visual studio is using. For example take a look at [Custom Color Palette in Visual Studio Color Property Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35840268/3110834). But the first option is easier to achieve.

Comment: I've included the BaseForm and Culture classes in my namespace but when i use FormGPS:BaseForm to make my mainform of application, all controls are inaccessible due to protection level - but all are public. Thoughts?